# ng-template with material menu

Tags: html, angular-material, menu

I'm working on a boilerplate project with a configurable menu structure. The menu in it is bound to a recursive data type. I want to solve this via ng-container and ng-template as it looks to me that this is the only way to execute certain steps recursivly.

I have already developed several components using material so I would like to stick with material components as well and not use another menu component.

**The problem I have is that if the mat-menu items are defined in a ng-template the menu doesn't get rendered properly. [https://i.imgur.com/WQed1yb.gif]**

A menu-trigger-for menu item doesn't seem to be rendered the way it should. It lacks the sub-menu icon, and hovering over it doesn't show up the sub-menu. Instead a click is required. Furthermore the parent menu disappears when the sub-menu is opened which can complicate navigating through the menu.

Besides the mentioned issue the menu by itself does seem to work though.

I tried lazy loading based on a example here: https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/menu/ but that
didn't solve the issue.

My HTML template is as follows:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="itemMenu">
  {{ startMenuItem.description }}
</button>
<mat-menu #itemMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let childItem of startMenuItem.children">
    <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenuTmpl; context: { $implicit: childItem }"
    >
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</mat-menu>

<ng-template #recursiveMenuTmpl let-parentItem>
  <ng-container *ngIf="parentItem.children">
    <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="menuItem; context: { $implicit: parentItem }"
    ></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!parentItem.children">
    <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="singleItem; context: { $implicit: parentItem }"
    ></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #menuItem let-rootItem>
  <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="itemMenu" mat-menu-item>
    {{ rootItem.description }}
  </button>
  <mat-menu #itemMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let childItem of rootItem.children">
      <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenuTmpl; context: { $implicit: childItem }"
      >
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-menu>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #singleItem let-item>
  <button *ngIf="item.route" mat-menu-item [routerLink]="item.uri">
    {{ item.description }}
  </button>
  <button *ngIf="!item.route" mat-menu-item (click)="onOpenUrl(item.uri)">
    {{ item.description }}
  </button>
</ng-template>
```

and my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-menu',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-menu.component.css'],
})
export class DynamicMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public startMenuItem: MenuItem = {
    description: 'Menu',
    uri: '',
    route: false,
    children: [
      {
        description: 'Welcome',
        uri: '',
        route: false,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        description: 'Other',
        uri: '',
        route: false,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        description: 'Sign on/off',
        uri: '',
        route: false,
        children: [
          {
            description: 'Login',
            uri: '',
            route: false,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            description: 'Logout',
            uri: '',
            route: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  constructor() {}

  public onOpenUrl(url: string) {
    document.location.href = url;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After doing some additional research i discovered that there was actually a bug in my code. The `ngIf` in my template that checks if a menu item has child items checked the existence of the child array and not if the array has actual content. I fixed that but it unfortunately didn't solve my original problem.

Further analysis of the behavior of the material menu showed that the parent child relationships weren't behaving as expected. This eventually directed me to an issue already raised for Angular (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842). I very much suspect that this issue is causing the menu to misbehave. Understanding this shortcoming I reworked my template such that only one `ng-template` is used.

The problem material menu has is that is lacking content children (at least in my case as the children are in the ng-template). However if the reference from `mat-menu` is passed along with the template then a custom directive (or at least that is how I fixed it) in the template can do a content children and set the result in the parent `mat-menu`. Setting `_allItems` in the parent `mat-menu` with the content children and calling the `_updateDirectDescendants` was sufficient.

Unfortunately dependency injection with directives in templates is problematic as well (see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2907) which prevents parent relationships from being set in the `menu-items` and `menu-trigger`. If the `parentMenu` of all `menuItems` is set to it's corresponding parent menu (via means of passing on the reference via the template context) that issue is solved as well for the `menuItems`.
On the menu trigger the `_parentMaterialMenu` needs to be set. Finally for the `matMenuItems` that trigger a sub-menu the `triggerSubMenu` should be set to true.

---

So the wrap it up:

1. Use one template or at least make sure the menu and the descendant menu-items are in one template.
2. Get the child `menuItems`  (e.g. via a custom directive) a set them in `_allItems` in the menu. Afterwards call `_updateDirectDescendants` on the menu.
3. Set all `menuItems` to have the `parentMenu` set to the actual parent menu.
4. On the `menuTrigger` the `_parentMaterialMenu` needs to be set to the actual parent menu.
5. The `menuItems` that trigger a submenu should have there `_triggerSubMenu` set to true.

---

And that's it, the menu should work as normal. Note that this fix doesn't rely on Angular API alone. It works for Angular material version 12, but it might also work on other versions as well.

The following code is a working example:

*Dynamic menu component html template*

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="itemMenu">{{ startMenuItem.description }}
    </button>
    <mat-menu #itemMenu="matMenu" #parentMenuRef>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenuTmpl; context: { $implicit: startMenuItem, parentMenuRef: parentMenuRef }"></ng-container>
    </mat-menu>
    <ng-template #recursiveMenuTmpl let-rootItem let-parentMenuRef="parentMenuRef">
      <ng-container appMenupatch [parentMenu]=parentMenuRef>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let childItem of rootItem.children" >
          <ng-container *ngIf="hasSubItems(childItem)">
            <button #triggerButton="matMenuItem" #trigger="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor]="patch(itemMenu, triggerButton, trigger, parentMenuRef)" mat-menu-item>
              {{ childItem.description }}
            </button>
            <mat-menu #itemMenu="matMenu" #parentMenuRefNew>
              <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenuTmpl; context: { $implicit: childItem, parentMenuRef: parentMenuRefNew }"></ng-container>
            </mat-menu>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="!hasSubItems(childItem)">
            <button *ngIf="childItem.route" mat-menu-item [routerLink]="childItem.uri">
              {{ childItem.description }}
            </button>
            <button *ngIf="!childItem.route" mat-menu-item (click)="onOpenUrl(childItem.uri)">
              {{ childItem.description }}
            </button>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
```

*Dynamic menu component ts*

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenu, MatMenuItem, MatMenuPanel, _MatMenuBase } from '@angular/material/menu';

export interface MenuItem {
  description: string,
  uri: string,
  route: boolean,
  children: MenuItem[]
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-menu',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-menu.component.css'],
})

export class DynamicMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public startMenuItem: MenuItem = {
    description: 'Menu',
    uri: '',
    route: false,
    children: []
   };

  constructor() {}

  public onOpenUrl(url: string) {
    document.location.href = url;
  }

  public hasSubItems(item: MenuItem):boolean{
    return (Array.isArray(item.children) && item.children.length>0);
  }

  public patch(item: MatMenu, triggerbutton: MatMenuItem, trigger: any, parentMenu: MatMenuPanel):MatMenu
  {
    if (parentMenu)
    {
        triggerbutton._triggersSubmenu=true;
        trigger._parentMaterialMenu=parentMenu;
    }
    return item;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let menuItem = {
      description: 'Canine',
      route: true,
      children: 
    [
      {
        description: 'Dog',
        route: false
      },
      {
        description: 'Wolve',
        route: false
      }
    ]
    } as MenuItem;
    this.startMenuItem.children.push(menuItem);
    menuItem = {
      description: 'Rodent',
      route: true,
      children:[
        {
          description: 'Rabbit',
          route: false
        },
        {
          description: 'Beaver',
          route: false
        },
        {
          description: 'Mouse',
          route: false
        }
      ]
    } as MenuItem;
    this.startMenuItem.children.push(menuItem);
    menuItem = {
      description: 'Bird of prey',
      route: true,
      children:
      [
        {
          description: 'Eagle',
          route: false
        },
        {
          description: 'Falcon',
          route: false
        },
        {
          description: 'Harrier',
          route: false
        }
      ]
    } as MenuItem;
    this.startMenuItem.children.push(menuItem);
  }
}
```

Menu-patch directive

```js
import { Directive, Input, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuItem } from '@angular/material/menu';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMenupatch]'
})
export class MenupatchDirective {
  @ContentChildren(MatMenuItem, {descendants: true}) _allItems: QueryList<MatMenuItem>;
  @Input() parentMenu: any;
  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(){
    this._allItems.forEach(item=>{
      item._parentMenu=this.parentMenu;
    })
    this.parentMenu._allItems=this._allItems;
    this.parentMenu._updateDirectDescendants();
  }

}
```

The model declarations should contain:

```
 - DynamicMenuComponent
 - MenupatchDirective
```

The imports should have the material module components:

```
- MatMenuModule
- MatButtonModule
```

Comment: Having the exactly same issue when trying to generate a recursive menu via ng-template. Can you please add a working example?

Comment: I have one in my github repo which is integrated in the project [https://github.com/jeroen-v-g/solar] if I have time I will extract it and update it here.

Comment: Thank you very much! Guess that's ok for now. As far as I know there is still no better solution. This use-case should be pretty common, isn't it?

Comment: Your solution is way better than the regular behavior, but it still won't open / close on hover, does it?

Comment: That is behavior of the material button, hovering over menu-items should work.

Comment: Still works with Angular 16

Answer (score 0):

Tried to solve this with templates too, after hours of attempts and web searches I managed to make it work by using a recursive component. I edited an old Angular 4 solution of someone else. Sharing a working example tested on Angular 13.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-hover-mat-menu-nosubitem-support-ifcyo8