# Mat-Menu with cascading content inside multiple ng-template keep auto closing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this menu that needs to be inside ng-template for multiple use cases. And soon the submenu of the main menu is inside a ng-template, the submenu structure stops working.

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu3">
  Submenu in cascading containers and templates
</button>
<mat-menu #menu3="matMenu">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="mainMenu3"></ng-container>
</mat-menu>

<ng-template #mainMenu3>
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu3">
    Submenu in a template
  </button>
  <mat-menu #subMenu3>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="subSubNenu3"></ng-container>
  </mat-menu>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #subSubNenu3>
  <button mat-menu-item>Submenu Item</button>
</ng-template>
```

How do I avoid this behavior and make it work properly?

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-submenu-npscht?file=app%2Fnested-menu-example.html) version of it. Just ignore the commented code.

The original Stackblitz code comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67123501/material-submenu-in-separate-component-doesnt-open-on-mouseover).